# Cannot be accessed with an instance reference after code conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, instance-reference

I have the following code which was created after using the telerik code converter to translate a piece of legacy code into C# but it is yielding the error

**Error 473 Member 'System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(System.IO.Stream, System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead**

```
public virtual string Serialize()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
    System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
    try
    {
        memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = false;
        System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = xmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
        Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     }
     finally
     {
         if ((((streamReader) != null)))
         {
             streamReader.Dispose();
         }
         if ((((memoryStream) != null)))
         {
             memoryStream.Dispose();
         }
     }
}
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = xmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
```

In VB.Net the code was as follows:

```
Public Overridable Function Serialize() As String
    Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Try
        memoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim xmlWriterSettings As System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings = New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings()
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = False
        Dim xmlWriter As System.Xml.XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings)
        Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, Me)
        memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        streamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream)
        Return streamReader.ReadToEnd
    Finally
        If (Not (streamReader) Is Nothing) Then
            streamReader.Dispose()
        End If
        If (Not (memoryStream) Is Nothing) Then
            memoryStream.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casing is incorrect. Try changing `xmlWriter.Create` to `XmlWriter.Create` (with a capital X).  I'm not sure why the converter changed that on you. It apparently just got confused because the variable and type names were the same.

Comment: Thanks Steven really should have worked that out :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems kinda invalid in most of the languages I have used so far

```
type varName = varName.DoSmth();
```

The confusion of the automatic conversion tool comes from the similarity of the type and the variable name. You need to call `Create()` as a static method from `XmlWriter`

```
System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
```

P.S.: It is never good idea to use tools to generate code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Royal I know its not a good means of generating code I just thought it might be handy to understand what is going on by converting it to C# where it is a lot more readable to me